# Triangle inequality with minus

Tags: inequality

Is the following inequality valid:
$$|x-y|\le|x|+|y|$$
I couldn't find this explicitly stated but using the triangle inequality: $$|x+(-y)| \le |x| + |-y| = |x| + |y|.$$
I wanted to clarify that this result was correct.

Comment: It is correct !

Comment: @Amateur Excellent!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed you are correct (and you've certainly shown) that this follows from the triangle inequality.